# JMeter result log does not include parent samples while running in NON-GUI mode, I need the parent samples

Tags: jmeter

I need to run JMeter in NON-GUI mode. GUI mode will not work for me.
I created a JMeter test plan structured like this

- [image]

I ran JMeter in NON_GUI mode with this command:

> jmeter -n -t accessories.jmx -l C:\Users\YuC1\Desktop\output.csv

In the output.csv, only all the child samplers' results were included.

The problem for it is:

- The result does not include parent sampler's name(transaction controllers), so I cannot analyse based on each transaction controller.

In a similar question on stackoverflow:

- "JMeter: view Results Tree with parent and child samples after running in NON-GUI mode"

It is mentioned his/her problem for it was: it only included parent sampler results(which is what I wanted) without child samplers.

I think the solution should be in the jmeter.properties file, but I could not find the configuration to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plan, you checked "Generate Parent Sample" in [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller).

So when using CSV output as per your command line, in JMeter <= 4.0, only parent sample result will be output.

Note that your configuration is not advised to generate HTML Report:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_requirements

Anyway, in upcoming JMeter 5.0, this will change and Child Samples will also be output as per:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62470

You can try nightly build which is very close to what 5.0 will be as we are very close to releasing:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Comment: Thank you. I did check "Generate Parent Sample", but I tried again, this time it worked, I think I might used the wrong .jmx file in my command line. Thank you for the quick response.